# ¿Como puedo asignar un valor a una variable dentro de un button

Tags: vue.js, axios, nativescript

estoy desarrollando en NativeScript-vue logre hacer aparecer "N" botones según cuantos datos obtengo de una API axios

```
<template>
  <Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" actionBarHidden="true"> 
    <ActionBar title="Login" class="action-bar" />
    <Gradient direction="to right" colors="#FFFFFF">

      <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column" justifyContent="center" class="full-height">

            <StackLayout class="container">
                            <Label textWrap="true" class="text" >
            <FormattedString>
              <Span text="Selecciona el tipo de evaluacion:" />

            </FormattedString>
          </Label>    

        ***<Button v-for="(btn,index) in btns" :key="index" :text="btn.type_name" @tap="next()" height="70 " class="my-button" ></Button>***  

            </StackLayout>

      </FlexboxLayout>

    </Gradient>
  </Page>
</template>
```

bueno también logre que aparezca con su respectivo nombre y pues ahora necesito el id del dato para consumir otra API Axios,
es decir necesito que este en una variable el id para usar esa variable en mi próximo método

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      btns:[],
      btnid:"",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    next(){
        this.btnid++;
          axios.get('https://obtengo otro {id,name} pero debo mandar {id del botón que genere}')
          .then(res=>{
          //  this.$router.push('/evl')
              alert({
                          title: "Unifranz",
                          message: res.data.Evaluation[0].evl_name,
                          okButtonText: "OK"
                  });
          })
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    axios.get('https://obtengo datos {id,name}')
    .then(response=>{
     this.btns=response.data.Type_Evaluation
    })
    .catch(error=>{})
  }

}
</script>}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es mandar el `id` en `@tap="next()"` ejemplo:

```
<Button v-for="(btn,index) in btns" :key="index" :text="btn.type_name" @tap="next(btn.id)" height="70 " class="my-button" ></Button>
```

Ya solo recibes el id de la forma:

```
next($id){
        this.btnid++;
          axios.get('https://obtengo otro {id,name} pero debo mandar {id del botón que genere}')
          .then(res=>{
          //  this.$router.push('/evl')
              alert({
                          title: "Unifranz",
                          message: res.data.Evaluation[0].evl_name,
                          okButtonText: "OK"
                  });
          })
    }
```

Y lo utilizas de la forma que lo requieres en axios.